# Mutex locking numerous times

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, mutex

As far as I know, mutexes should lock once and then block others until freed, like this.

[image]

But with my code, it seems like multiple threads are locking the same mutex. I have a thread pool of 10, so surely 9 should block and 1 should lock. But I get this output.

```
Thread 0 got locked 
Thread 1 got locked 
Thread 3 got locked 
Thread 4 got locked 
Thread 2 got locked 
Thread 5 got locked 
Thread 6 got locked 
Thread 7 got locked 
Thread 8 got locked 
Thread 9 got locked
```

My mutex is defined globally at the top of *.c file as,

```
pthread_mutex_t queuemutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

And here are relevant code segments.

```
    //In the main function which creates all the threads
int k;
for (k = 0; k < POOLSIZE; k++) {
    pthread_t thread;
    threadinformation *currentThread = (threadinformation *)malloc(sizeof(threadinformation));
    currentThread->state = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    currentThread->state[0] = 0;
    currentThread->currentWaiting = currentWaiting;
    currentThread->number = k;
    threadArray[k] = currentThread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, readWriteToClient, threadArray[k]);
    currentThread->thread = thread;
    joinArray[k] = thread;
}
```

And here is the segment of code in which all 10 threads seem to get the lock.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&queuemutex);

fprintf(stderr,"Thread %d got locked \n",threadInput->number);

while((threadInput->currentWaiting->status) == 0){
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &queuemutex);
    fprintf(stderr,"Thread %d got signalled \n",threadInput->number);
}

connfd = threadInput->currentWaiting->fd;
threadInput->currentWaiting->status = 0;
pthread_cond_signal(&conncond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&queuemutex);
```

Comment: `int retcode = pthread_mutex_lock(&queuemutex); assert(retcode == 0);`

Comment: What is `currentWaiting`? or, more specifically, what is the initial value of `currentWaiting->status`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that `currentWaiting->status` is initially `0`.

Since that is the case, your code enters the while loop and waits on the condition variable.

Waiting on the condition variable unlocks the mutex until the wait completes, allowing the other threads to acquire it.

Comment: +1 That has to be correct. [pthread_cond_wait:](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) `These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;`

Comment: Superb, that has to be it, otherwise the mutex logic doesn't make sense.

So, very generally speaking, is it okay practice to have a cond_wait inside a mutex whilst the chunk of code is being run by multiple threads?

It doesn't seem to be causing a problem for my program, it was just frustrating! :)

Comment: perfect answer. Where did you get your psy. powers? ;)

Comment: @Geesh_SO The thread that ends up in the `pthread_cond_wait()` call will not do anything, so it will not generate any race condition. The tricky case is when the thread is woken up and the mutex is held somewhere else. In the later case, the `pthread_cond_wait()` will block until it locks the mutex. It is not dangerous though, but you should keep this in mind.

Comment: @Geesh_SO: That's generally how you do it. Whenever a thread wakes up from the wait it needs to re-acquire the mutex, so there will be a single thread holding the mutex once the loop completes.